# Is it possible to Scan rows that changed after a certain date in HBase?

Tags: java, hbase

I need to Scan my HBase table and return only those rows that changed in a given time period (EG: last hour). Note that I need the entire row and not only the cell/value that changed.

The table has billions of rows and a couple of column families. It is updated regularly (sometimes we update the entire row, sometimes only a given cell). Looking at the documentation it seems that the `TimestampFilter` returns only 'cells' and using `setTimeRange` in `Get` or `Scan` returns only 'columns'. I need the entire row, is it possible through the api? If not, what's an efficient workaround?

Answer (score 2):

With TimestampFilter you can get the cell that was written in given time period. If you want entire row, then you will need to do `get` on that particular rowkey. I dont think this is an efficient way. 
I would recommend you to build a TimeSeries table. Can you use timestamp as a Suffix in your rowkey?
Have a look at section 6.3.1: http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/rowkey.design.html

If you need to use timestamp as a prefix, then you will need to do `salting`. 
Have a look at this for salting: https://phoenix.apache.org/salted.html

Comment: I can't change the row key :(

Comment: @Gevorg: Then your only option is to do a GET after doing scan using TimeStamp filter.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you do updates for entire and only single column makes life difficult. I had a similar problem with get the count based on timestamp. Since the timestamp is at cell level, and we only insert entire row, I used a map reduce to group based on time stamp(format back to date), and then count. You can use a similar one, except that you should choose your individual columns, and when they are modified.